# Show progressbar on the top in the existing MainPage.xaml in UWP app(c++) by masking all the other controls in UI

Tags: c++, uwp

I have an UWP C++ app for getting some information which takes a long time to load .While startup,its taking time to get the information and update the UI.So I thought of putting a progress ring while the UI is getting data. I need the progress ring to show on the UI during the loading time in MainPage.xaml thereby making the existing controls invisible.But it is not coming on top of UI.After getting data to UI,progress ring should disappear and all the controls should be visible.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Ft_Information.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Ft_Information"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"  Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded" BorderThickness="10" IsTabStop="True">

  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ftnfoGrid" Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="500*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />

      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="800*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="ProductNameText"      x:Uid="ProductName"      TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" FontSize="13" IsReadOnly="True" />
       <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="55,5.333,0.333,-5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ProgressRing  Name="ProgressRingLbl" Height="120" Width="109" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Foreground="Blue" IsActive="True" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Grid>

</Page>


MainPage::MainPage()
{
    ProductNameText->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;
ProgressRingLbl->IsActive = true;
        ProgressRingLbl->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible;
}

MainPage::FuntouploadUI()
{
.............
//after getting data
ProgressRingLbl->IsActive = false;
        ProgressRingLbl->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;

ProductNameText->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible;

}
```

Still the progress bar is not showing anywhere in the UI.

Comment: According to your code,we found you miss a **</stackPanel>**,maybe it is a typo.When I tested this code,the progress ring does appear on the top of UI.But  just this code,I'm not clear what the specific reason is.Maybe because the actual loading time is very short causes the progress ring doesn't appear.So can you show us a sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I tried the progress ring in seperate <Grid x:Name="progressGrid">...</Grid>.But it is not showing in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why progress ring not working was we are using another view to show the mainpage.xaml as a child to its root grid.When I moved the progress ring part to that xaml ,it is working fine. Since progress ring is working as a seperate UI thread it is not called by the mainpage.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple demo below.You can use this code in your application to test if the progress ring can show in the UI.

```
<Page ...>   
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue">
       <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Height="50" FontSize="16" Margin="0,20,0,20">Hello,world</TextBlock>​
       <Button x:Name="MyButton" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>​
       <ProgressRing x:Name="MyProgressRing" Height="120" Width="109" Foreground="Blue" IsActive="True" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ProgressRing>​
     </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Page>

MainPage::MainPage()
{​
  InitializeComponent();​

  MyTextBlock->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;​
  MyButton->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;​
  MyProgressRing->IsActive = true;​
  MyProgressRing->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible;​
​
}
```